# How can I calculate the time complexity for merge sort?

Tags: python

How do I Add counter to count the number of primitive operations in python for this program? And how do I plot the worst case, best case, and average case for time complexity?

```
def mergeSort(ar_list):
if len(ar_list) > 1:
    mid = len(ar_list) // 2
    left = ar_list[:mid]
    right = ar_list[mid:]
  # Recursive call on each half
   mergeSort(left)
   mergeSort(right)
 # Two iterators for traversing the left and right half
  i = 0
  j = 0
 # Iterator for the main list
  k = 0
while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
  if left[i] < right[j]:
  # The value from the left half has been used
   ar_list[k] = left[i]
   # Move the iterator forward
    i += 1
   else:
  ar_list[k] = right[j]
  j += 1
  k += 1
# For all the remaining values
 while i < len(left):
 ar_list[k] = left[i]
  i += 1
  k +=1
 while j < len(right):
   ar_list[k]=right[j]
    j += 1
     k += 1
ar_list = [12, 7, 2, 9, 4, 15, 5]
mergeSort(ar_list)
print(ar_list)
```

Can anyone find a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exact way to definitively calculate the exact time complexity of a function. As explained in the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

But:

- You can estimate it with the [`big_o`](https://github.com/pberkes/big_O#usage) library
- You can calculate it (to a general equation) yourself through observation

  - [How to](https://adrianmejia.com/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm-code-big-o-notation/)
  - You may need to google the time complexities for each built-in python function
  - I recommend this option

If you want to add a counter to your code for each operation, you will need to edit it manually to increase a counter variable. The example below depicts how you would approach this problem

```
def foo(x):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(10):
        x += 1
        # x is accessed. += 1 for counter
        counter += 1
    return x, counter
```

```
>>> foo(100)
(110, 10)
```

The variable was accessed `10` times

As your function is recursive, you will need to pass counter as an argument so it continues to be increased

```
def foo(x, counter=0):
    if x <= 0:
        return 0, counter
    else:
        return foo(x-1, counter=counter + 1)
```

```
>>> print(foo(123))
(0, 123)
```

---

There are infinite ways to plot a graph, it all depends on what you want. I suggest having a read of [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/).

Here is a quick example:

```
# From https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#coding-styles

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)  # Sample data of resulution 100

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 2.7), layout='constrained')

ax.plot(x, x, label='O(n)')  # Plot some data on the axes.
ax.plot(x, x**2, label='O(n^2)')  # Plot more data on the axes...
ax.plot(x, x**3, label='O(n^3)')  # ... and some more.

ax.set_xlabel('x label')  # Add an x-label to the axes.
ax.set_ylabel('y label')  # Add a y-label to the axes.
ax.legend()  # Add a legend.

plt.show()
```

> https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#coding-styles

[image: matplotlib figure]

---

Please split your questions into multiple posts when they are large and of different domain next time :)